# Versioning error when creating a Topology on a File GDB

Tags: arcpy, topology, versioning, error-999999

Im having an issue with the 99999 Error. Im creating a Topology dataset for each of the featureclasses within a GDB. For some reason my script works for some feature classes and errors on others. I was having an issue with the "add rules" tool, and switched background processing off, which seemed to have fixed that error. However, I now get this unknown error...

> Cannot register as versioned on this database. Failed to execute
>   (AddRuleToTopology).

Has anyone had this issue before, before I go and log this with ESRI?

My script:

```
ws = arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
fc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
log_write("starting to create topologies for {}".format(workspace))

for f in fc:
    fc_name = arcpy.Describe(f).name[4:]
    log_write("creating topology for {}".format(fc_name))

    sr = arcpy.Describe(f).spatialreference
    log_write("spatial ref : {}".format(sr.name))

    input_dataset = arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(ws, "{}_dataset".format(fc_name), sr)
    log_write("dataset created")

    new_fc = arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(f, input_dataset, fc_name)
    log_write("added fc to feature dataset")

    topo = arcpy.CreateTopology_management(input_dataset, "Topology", 0.001)
    log_write("topology created")

    arcpy.AddFeatureClassToTopology_management(topo, new_fc, 1)
    log_write("fc added to toplogy")

    arcpy.AddRuleToTopology_management(topo, "Must Not Have Gaps (Area)", new_fc)
    arcpy.AddRuleToTopology_management(topo, "Must Not Overlap (Area)", new_fc)
    log_write("rules added to topology")

    arcpy.ValidateTopology_management(topo)
    log_write("topology validated")
```

Comment: Could you add whether this ran interactively (outside script)? Also, is this file GDB a replica database or a check-in, check-out source for ArcPad>

Comment: This is using a File GDB, which i have copied into a working area. This script is run in ArcCatalog. I have created a toolbox script to try and run this using user input.

Comment: Just to add, this error occurs when trying to add rules to the Topology dataset. i have checked this topology dataset manually, and it doesnt add the featureclass from the line above too, which is strange.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the exact same error now...

Comment: kind of. I included a try, except statement which allowed the scripts to continue, but then show me which ones I had to create manually. I renamed the topology dataset to "manual" when this errored out. it didn't fix the problem, but didn't stop the script from running.